# #REF!, How to Grab the first response of form and ignore the duplicate in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a google form for attendance and I have a formula to automatically calculate the salary from the attendance. Sometimes people fill out the attendance twice with the same status (work/go home) and I don't want to change the form settings. So what I want is if there is 2 response from the same person, on the same day, with the same status, just grab the first response and ignore the second status so the data won't double in the salary form. What formula can I use to do that? Please help me guys, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

`=arrayformula(query({A2:C,if(len(A2:A),row(A2:A)-match(text(date(year(A2:A),month(A2:A),day(A2:A)),"dd-MM-yyyy")&B2:B&C2:C,text(date(year(A2:A),month(A2:A),day(A2:A)),"dd-MM-yyyy")&B2:B&C2:C,0),)},"select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col1 is not null and Col4 = 1"))`

---

**Sample**

[image: snapshot]

---

**Logic**

- There are 2 ranges in the query
- `A2:C` - the raw data
- `if(len(A2:A),row(A2:A)-match(text(date(year(A2:A),month(A2:A),day(A2:A)),"dd-MM-yyyy")&B2:B&C2:C,text(date(year(A2:A),month(A2:A),day(A2:A)),"dd-MM-yyyy")&B2:B&C2:C,0),)` - this does several things:

  - `text(date(year(A2:A),month(A2:A),day(A2:A)),"dd-MM-yyyy")`- converts the timestamp to a date string
  - `text()&B2:B&C2:C` - builds a unique string consisting of the date, the user's name and the code
  - `row(A2:A)-match(text...)` - this finds matches of the unique string and  returns an index. if the value = 1, then it is the first occurrence of the unique string; if the value is greater than 1, then it is a later occurrence of the unique string.
- the query is in 3 parts

  - `select Col1, Col2, Col3` - returns the data columns (Timestamp, Name & Code)
  - `where Col1 is not null` - limits the results to rows containing a datestamp
  - `and Col4 = 1` - limits the results to the first instance of the unique string.